# Git status shows all the files is it correct?

Tags: git, ubuntu

This is what I read from http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

but in my case it shows all the file from the `~` home directory. Is that correct?

Comment: You need to paste what you get and tell us if you are on the root of your git project and whether you changed the files shown since your last commit.

Comment: You should paste in the output of `git status`, but I would guess you have not added the files in your directory to the repo, or have not made a commit. `git add .` would add all the current directory files to the repo (if that's whay you want to do).

Comment: but now i command like " git status django-example " now its showing fine ..

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you ran `git init` in your home directory. This can be quite problematic; check that this is the case by checking if `~/.git/` exists. If it does, you should remove that.

And remember that a bare `git init` will initialize a repo in the current directory, so you only want to run that in a new directory you've created for your project. Alternatively you can run `git init <path>` and git will initialize a new repo in the given path.